# How to merge 2 table fields in a database using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Is there a way to do this using mysql query? I want to merge the top 2 fields and rename it as "Report" but still the contents are separated in cells. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: this should happen on the application level. *Not the work of the RDBMS* `:)`

Comment: how do you display the table?

Comment: But I am implementing export function to xls format and the format could be manipulated through a mysql query.